# Aggregate boundaries

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

[Can an Entity be Shared across many Aggregates?](http://domain-driven-design.3010926.n2.nabble.com/Can-an-Entity-be-Shared-across-many-Aggregates-td7579277.html)

**Question**

> Can an entity be shared across many aggregates?  In the Blue Book (Evans), in chap 6 on aggregates there is an example of entities Tire and Wheel being used in the aggregate root Car.  If this example was extended to have two aggregates, Car and Truck would it be acceptable to use Tire and Wheel again with Truck?

**Answer**

> No. The reason why is the aggregate maintains invariants, how would one 
>   aggregate notify the other on change of an entity... If it didn't then you 
>   could possibly have an aggregate in an invalid state.
>
> Yes likely you want it as it's own aggregate with soft links. Btw there is 
>   no problem accessing the id of an entity from outside, the problem is the 
>   same entity being in two aggregates.
>
> Greg

**And my question**

It's not a problem to reference an identity of an external aggreagate root from your aggregate.

Let's assume we have the aggregate root `Resource` which belongs to the aggregate root `Device`.
`UpdateResource`

```
{
    "id":"933be22c-6e1f-11e8-adc0-fa7ae01bbebc",
    "userId":"2bf9d69a-6e20-11e8-adc0-fa7ae01bbebc",
    "deviceId":"a6caeaea-6e1f-11e8-adc0-fa7ae01bbebc",
    ...
}
```

Command was issued by a user identified by unique ID. The user is member of 1..n `Group`s. `Devices` belongs also to 1..n `Group`s as ell. 
Now my question is, if I want to verify if the user who did the request is in the same group as the device to which request applies, do I really need to query different aggregate? That would mean load same events as are maintained by aggregate `Devices`.

It's clear that two aggegates can't update the same entity - in this case `Device`. But aggregate `Resource` would just load it to validate the request. It's faster to do it internally in the aggerate rather then issuing command to different aggregate.

Or? :) Thanks

Comment: Is this an authorization check/invariant? it seems so...

Comment: Yes, it is authorization check. == Invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I want to verify if the user who did the request is in the same group as the device to which request applies, do I really need to query different aggregate?

In CQRS one does not query the write model, by definition. In DDD, the write model is the Aggregate. The Aggregate should not depend on (use) data that it does not own. This rule forces us to put the code where it belongs, to check the invariant in the correct Aggregate. In CQRS, the "data" are the (Domain) Events.

> That would mean load same events as are maintained by aggregate Devices

This would also mean that one Aggregate uses "data" from another Aggregate, so don't do it.

The business invariant `a user may only update the devices from the same group as him` seems to belong to a different Bounded context, namely Authorization. This means that there is no way with your current Aggregate boundary that this rule is enforced in a strong consistent manner. Strong consistency is guaranteed only inside a single Aggregate instance. In this case there is always the possibility that a user could update a device that he is not supposed to. This situation cannot be safely prevented. So, you need to design your system in such a way that it recovers from this situation.

One way to recover from this is to have a Saga/Process manager that listen to relevant events and send compensations commands to bring the system as a hole back in the valid state (it reverts the modifications brought by invalid commands).

As an optimization, in order to limit the invalid cases (they will still happen, but at a lower frequency), you could intercept the commands sent by the user to the device and reject those that are invalid. This mechanism is in fact an authorization check. Authorization checks are done *before* the command reaches an Aggregate. You still need to have that Saga, just in case some user is removed from the device groups *at the same time* it sends the command to the device.

Comment: "In CQRS one does not query the write model, by definition." True. My mistake.

"This means that there is no way with your current Aggregate boundary that this rule is enforced in a strong consistent manner." I don't need strong consistency. I can live with eventual consistency. But how to check the invariant from a different Bounded context - Authorization? So verify if user can proceed that request?

Comment: @OndrejTomcik You make a `DeviceAutheticationReadmodel` that listen to the user and device events, it builds an internal states of user - groups and device - groups; it has a method called `canUserSendCommandToDevice(userId, deviceId)` that uses that private data to answer `true` or `false`; in the Application layer, before sending the command to the Aggregate, you call this method.

Comment: Aggregate itself cannot check it? Why?

Comment: @OndrejTomcik no, authorization is in another bounded context

Comment: But the aggregate itself is the last entrypoint before the device is requested. Device does not know if user is authorized or not. Ao I have to think again about boundaries. But curious, why it is not allowed to access invariant of different bounded context? What are drawbacks?

Comment: @OndrejTomcik a CLEAN domain model.  It's not its responsibility. What has to do authorization with the device itself? Nothing. You need to extract the authorization logic outside of the Device Aggregate. All the DDD books talk about this.

Comment: @OndrejTomcik identifying the Bounded contexts/subdomains is the hardest thing, hold on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173005/discussion-between-ondrej-tomcik-and-constantin-galbenu).

Comment: You probably don't need the saga at all. Does it really matter if the access is revoked at about the same time the action took place? Obviously, it might look slightly odd in the logs that the access got removed perhaps 1ms before the action took place, but it would also be very easy to understand why this may have happened if you understand your model and shouldn't be an issue in most domains. Implementing a saga to issue compensating actions seems like unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is, if I want to verify if the user who did the request is in the same group as the device to which request applies, do I really need to query different aggregate?

Sort of.

The basic discipline of aggregates is that aggregates are responsible for changing their own state.  The information that they use to change their own state is their previous state, and the information passed to them as arguments.

So if you want to *query* the domain, to know for example if a user is a member of the right groups, then you would normally do that by passing the query to `Resource` as one of the arguments of the command.

The usual pattern for passing the query around is "domain service" - we're going to pass to the aggregate an interface that supports some query, and excuse the aggregate from the responsibility of implementing it.

```
Resource::updateResource(Command c, PermissionsService p) {
    if (p.hasPermission(c.userId, c.deviceId)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

A simple implementation of the PermissionsService might simply pull the required state out of the repositories.

> It's faster to do it internally in the aggerate rather then issuing command to different aggregate.

I suspect that there are cases where efficient load and store of data doesn't fall along neat aggregate boundaries.  I'm certain that you should keep such concerns out of the domain logic of the aggregates themselves, but that doesn't mean you can't replace the loading strategy with something more efficient.

I think of it this way: PermissionsService is going to need to access a copy of the relations between Device and Groups.  We're not modifying these relationships, so in effect we're just working with a cached copy.  That means that we can, at our discretion, *seed the cache with representations we expect to be useful* before handing that cache off to the domain logic for actual work.

Side note: once you start thinking about caching data, you begin to recognize that your calls into other aggregates may be *temporal* queries.  "Now" is subjective, but "when your clock said time t" isn't.  So your query code might really look like

```
Resource::updateResource(Command c, PermissionsService p) {
    Time time = ... 

    if (p.hasPermission(c.userId, c.deviceId, time)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

With *three* state logic in your queries

- I have access to a representation valid at that time, and the answer is yes
- I have access to a representation valid at that time, and the answer is no
- I don't have access to a representation valid at that time